# Lua / Love2d physics setCallback - how to correctly create a callback to a method of an object

Tags: oop, lua, callback, love2d

I'm still struggling with the basics of Lua and Love2d while adding some physics to my first game prototype:

Creating a local or global (non method) collision callback function, that is called when two objects collide works like a charm.
Now - As all my game elements are objects (even the game area) I tried to create the callback function as a method of the area-object with no success:

It seems that `Area:beginContact` assumes that the first parameter is the instance of the object. As  `self.world:setCallbacks` is not aware of that, this will to all parameter of the call being shiftes to the left: fixture_a within the callback function becomes filled with fixture_b, fixture_b with contact and contact is becoming nil.

I tried to solve this problem by defining the callback as `self.world:setCallbacks(self:beginContact)`. I thought this would force the first parameter to be set as the instance of the object, but this just leads to an error.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

```
function Area:new(room)
    self.room = room
    self.game_objects = {}
    self.physics_objects = {}
    love.physics.setMeter(64)
    self.world = love.physics.newWorld(0, 0, true)
    self.world:setCallbacks(self.beginContact) <---- here's the problem
end

function Area:beginContact(fixture_a, fixture_b, contact)
    print(self)
    local name_a = fixture_a:getUserData()
    local name_b = fixture_b:getUserData()
  
    print(name_a, name_b, contact, '!!beginning contact')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation: https://love2d.org/wiki/World:setCallbacks

I'm just a beginner, but perhaps rename `Area:beginContact` to `AreaBeginContact` and use `setCallbacks(AreaBeginContact,...)`. On collision that is called can get the Area from the fixtures

```
function AreaBeginContact(fixture_a, fixture_b, contact)
    (...)
    local fixture_area = fixture_a:getArea()
```

(you would need to implement getArea function), and do Area-specific stuff.

Comment: Yes, that would work (it's my currenty work around) but is not using a method but a function for the callback (AreaBeginContact in that Case is not part of an area object)

Comment: @Paraglider0815 I don't think it is possible the way you want, because the collision callback given by setCallbacks is global. It detects collisions between all objects. If you wanted for it to detect collision only within an Area, you would need to rewrite love2d collision routine (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @Paraglider0815 It may be possible however to do this rewrite of love, but may not be worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I feared that a non-global callback-function would require a modification of love (that's a path I don't want to go), but I hoped that I just missed an easy different solution due to my missing experience.